# kscript : How to get directory of current file?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

Is there a way to get directory of a current script location in kotlin script?

I could achieve this in bash with

```
 dirname $0
```

or

```
# Absolute path to this script. /home/user/bin/foo.sh
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
# Absolute path this script is in. /home/user/bin
SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPT`
```

Answer (score 2):

The builtin `kotlin-main-kts` script definition adds a `__FILE__` variable to the script context. Access works just as you'd expect:

```kotlin
println(__FILE__) // java.io.File object representing /home/user/bin/foo.main.kts (or wherever the script is)
println(__FILE__.parentFile) // java.io.File object representing /home/user/bin
println(__FILE__.absolutePath) // the string /home/user/bin/foo.main.kts
println(__FILE__.parent) // the string /home/user/bin
```

You can also change the name of the variable using the annotation `ScriptFileLocation`:

```kotlin
@file:ScriptFileLocation("scriptPath")
println(scriptPath.absolutePath) // /home/user/bin/foo.main.kts
```

Keep in mind IntelliJ autocomplete doesn't love changing the variable name like that, though. :-)

So how do you run your script with `kotlin-main-kts`? In Kotlin 1.3.70 and above, it's as easy as ensuring your script's name ends in `.main.kts`. The compiler will automatically apply this special context, giving you access to `__FILE__`. For more information, check out the Kotlin repository [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-script-examples/blob/master/jvm/main-kts/MainKts.md).

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

`File(".")`

and don't forget to `import java.io.File`

Comment: that gives me just "." as output :(

Comment: use `.absolutePath`

Comment: this is the working directory which may or may not be the directory in which the script resides.